# Read from SharePoint with SPServices

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010, spservices

I am trying to read from a SharePoint list("Winners") and display it on a page using content editor. This sounds really simple but for some reason I'm having a hard time with this. My code to do this is below:

```
<style type="text/css">
  h4{
  color: red

}
table{
border: #ccc solid 2px;
border-radius: 3px;

}

</style>

<script src="/_layouts/1033/FH/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/FH/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    GetWinners();

}):

//getWinners Function starts here.
function GetWinners(){

    //Variables to store information.
    var method = "GetListItems";
    var list = "Winners";
    var fieldsToRead =  "<ViewFields>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Picture' />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Text' />" +
                        "</ViewFields>";

    var query = "<Query>" +
                    "<Where>" +
                        "<Neq>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>0</Value>" + 
                        "</Neq>" +
                    "</Where>" +
                    "<OrderBy>" + 
                        "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
                    "</OrderBy>" +
                "</Query>";

    //SPServices call where we pass the above variables.
    $().SPServices({
        operation: method,
        async: false,
        listName: list,
        CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
            CAMLQuery: query,
                completefunc: function (xData, Status){
                     $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
                        var name = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
                        var pictureUrl = ($(this).attr("ows_Picture"));
                        var caption = ($(this).attr("ows_Text"));

                        AddRowToTable(name, pictureUrl, caption);

                    });

                }

    });
}//End

//Function to add content on the page starts here.
function AddRowToTable(name, pictureUrl, caption){
    $("#winnersTable").append("<tr align:'middle'>" +
                                "<td><img src='"+ pictureUrl + "'/><br><h4>" + name + "</h4><br><p>" + caption + "</p></td>" +
                               "</tr>");

}

</script>

<!-- table where the winners would go -->
<div>
<table id="winnersTable"></table>
</div>
```

It will be a great help if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong. I have all the internal name of fields and list correct, so that's not the issue. Perhaps I'm missing up when I try to reference it from content editor. I hope I explained this right, but please let me know if there is any questions.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo at line:

```
}):
```

It is supposed to be semicolon instead of colon.

### Some recommendations

**Place markup in CEWP, but not a JavaScript code**

In fact it depends, but still there are some Pros here. First of all it concerns the maintenance and support of JavaScript code base

**Usage of common libraries**

It is recommended to reference a JavaScript libraries (like `jQuery`) from a master pages rather than from web parts.

Comment: Lol.. I noticed that right after I posted this. Thank you for catching that.